# Larger font sizes when usis POST statuses/update twitter developer api

Tags: css, api, twitter, python-twitter

I am successfully using the python-twitter api [python-twitter](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter) to update the status of a twitter account. But the font sizes are larger that than the other tweets. Firebug inspection shows that api update has a "TweetTextSize.TweetTextSize--26px" css class whereas the other tweets have a "TweetTextSize.TweetTextSize--16px" css class. My client will like to have the same font sizes. I am not sure if this can be changed

Comment: Can you give us an example of some of the tweets with different sizes?

Comment: [link to twitter account](https://twitter.com/alpha1cdnreg?ref_src=twsrc^tfw) The two identical tweets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, so this isn't something you can control from the API.

Twitter will *sometimes* increase the prominence of certain tweets based on whether its algorithms think the tweet is noteworthy.

For example, if a Tweet has a lot of retweets or likes, Twitter may temporarily increase the font size.

If you take a look at other accounts, you'll see that some of their Tweets will be bigger than others.

There's nothing you can do to control this, sorry.